# Laravel catch PDOException in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Tags: laravel, exception

I've noticied that I often write something like this

```
class SitesController
{
    public function update(SiteRequest $request, Site $site)
    {
        try {
            $site->update($request->all());

            return redirect()->route('sites.index');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('error', 'Cannot update site');
        }
    }

    public function destroy(Site $site)
    {
        try {
            $site->delete();

            return redirect()->route('sites.index');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('error', 'Cannot remove site');
        }
    }
}
```

Can I catch PDOException in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` like this? Is it good
idea? What are cons? Is there a way to catch PDOException that was thrown
from app/Http/Controllers folder only?

```
// app/Exceptions/Handler.php
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if (!App::runningInConsole() && $e instanceof PDOException) {
        return back()->with('error', 'Could not perform the operation');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many questions.. Did you try?

Yes you can if that is the last instance to catch it. If you need it at some deeper level in your code, use it there.

I like this approach for all 'User Facing Exceptions' - that should not be seen - , not something that I try and want to catch at a deeper level in the code.

Here you can have those exceptions organized and see what you don't throw at the user in one place.

For the last question, probably..., if you find a way to check where the exception was thrown.. something like debug_backtrace()[1]['function'] but thats probaly not working here... and use that in an if statement.

But you probably don't want that anyway because if a certain exception is thrown at any level in your code I don't think that you want to handle it differently depending on whether it was in the controller or not. Rather you want to show certain exceptions and others not, butif you really want that then I would catch the exception in the controller and return with what you want to return.

Add on:
You maybe don't just want to suppress the output but maybe also the logging. If so then put it in the $dontReport array further up in that Handler file and create a line like this in the report method: 
        `if (in_array(get_class($e), $this->dontReport)) return parent::report($e);`